# Hudson: HTTP listener already in use error

Tags: windows, hudson

I'm trying to setup Hudson on a Windows server.

When I attempt to run Hudson with the command `java -jar hudson.war`, then I receive an error that the address is already in use for the HTTP listener.

I've confirmed that port 8080 (the default Hudson HTTP port) is not being used. I have also tried starting Hudson on another port (`java -jar hudson.war --httpPort=8888`) with the same error.

If I browse to http://localhost:8080, then I get an 'It works!' message on the web page. However, if I browse to http://localhost:8080/hudson, I receive a 404 error.

Here is log:

```
D:\hudson>java -jar hudson.war
Running from: D:\hudson\hudson.war
[Winstone 2010/10/27 11:07:47] - Beginning extraction from war file
hudson home directory: C:\Documents and Settings\scottk\.hudson
[Winstone 2010/10/27 11:07:54] - Error during HTTP listener init or shutdown
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:102)
        at winstone.HttpListener.run(HttpListener.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[Winstone 2010/10/27 11:07:54] - HTTP Listener shutdown successfully
[Winstone 2010/10/27 11:07:54] - AJP13 Listener started: port=8009
Using one-time self-signed certificate
[Winstone 2010/10/27 11:07:54] - Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running: controlPort=disabled
Oct 27, 2010 11:07:55 AM hudson.model.Hudson$4 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Oct 27, 2010 11:07:56 AM hudson.model.Hudson$4 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Oct 27, 2010 11:07:56 AM hudson.model.Hudson$4 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Oct 27, 2010 11:07:56 AM hudson.model.Hudson$4 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Oct 27, 2010 11:07:57 AM hudson.model.Hudson$4 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Oct 27, 2010 11:08:01 AM hudson.model.Hudson$4 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Oct 27, 2010 11:08:01 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 1162
```

Port 8080 is not being used:

```
D:\>netstat -o

Active Connections

     Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
      TCP    dev1:1038              dev1.GCCU.local:15003  ESTABLISHED     1668
      TCP    dev1:1142              dev1.GCCU.local:1143   ESTABLISHED     1668
      TCP    dev1:1143              dev1.GCCU.local:1142   ESTABLISHED     1668
      TCP    dev1:1144              dev1.GCCU.local:1145   ESTABLISHED     1668
      TCP    dev1:1145              dev1.GCCU.local:1144   ESTABLISHED     1668
      TCP    dev1:15003             dev1.GCCU.local:1038   ESTABLISHED     1316
      TCP    dev1:1081              172.16.1.7:1000        ESTABLISHED     2100
      TCP    dev1:1127              app1.gccu.local:netbios-ssn  ESTABLISHED     4
      TCP    dev1:1129              gccufs1.gccu.local:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED     4
      TCP    dev1:1138              sql1.gccu.local:netbios-ssn  ESTABLISHED     4
      TCP    dev1:1167              dc2.gccu.local:microsoft-ds  TIME_WAIT       0
      TCP    dev1:ms-wbt-server     devpc1.gccu.local:54699  ESTABLISHED     2916
```

Comment: Are you sure 8080 is not in use? By default, netstat doesn't show listening ports, use `netstat -a`. Also, the 'It works' message is not what Hudson will display on startup. 'It works' sounds like a default web server welcome page. (I'm not sure why running on 8888 wouldn't work for you.)

Comment: You're right. There was something running on 8080. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend running Hudson from within a web application container such as Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the latest .war file from http://hudson-ci.org/download/war/, specified port 8888 instead of 8080, and now it works. Looks like there must be something running on port 8080 and  the version that I had tried to use earlier than 1.381 had an issue.